# How do I report an Ubuntu 16.04 kernel issue that was already uninstalled?

Tags: 16.04, sound, kernel, hardware

Recently got this kernel update about a day ago and caused an issue on my computer. Everything else was working fine. Only the audio was affected, as in it could not find the audio device at all, so it was on Dummy Output the whole time. The commands *lspci*, *inxi* and even *modprobe* does not list any sound device(s) and modules loaded, respectively, at all. Like it's non-existent.

The version I am trying to report is **4.4.0-128-generic**. But I cannot follow the instructions on this page - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs - since I have already reverted to the previous kernel below:

```
Linux Xenial-Xerus 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The audio is working fine now after reverting.

This also affected Windows 10 installed on the same machine. I booted to Windows when  I wasn't getting any sound on Ubuntu. On Windows I was getting "No audio output device is installed" error. Uninstalling/reinstalling the driver only resulted in more errors. Checking the properties of the hardware device says that it is not connected - Error code 45.

So to summarize:

1. If I use the 4.4.0-128 kernel, there is no audio. On Windows 10 there is no audio too.
2. If I use the 4.4.0-127 kernel, audio is okay. After this, restarting to Windows 10 the audio is okay too.

How Windows is even affected is weird.

Some details of my machine:

- ASUS K401UQ (UEFI with secure boot disabled)
- Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- Audio from lscpi -v

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 14b0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 131
    Memory at ef328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ef300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Normally you would reinstall the buggy kernel to file the bug report, and leave it installed so you can answer questions. Simply select a different (non-buggy) kernel at GRUB for your daily work.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that.  It seems troublesome though. Is there a chance this could ruin my device? If it affects both Ubuntu and Windows at the hardware level, because it seems to look that way, there's a chance it could exactly do just that. Don't want to risk it. I need a computer badly. This is the only one I have and I can't have it without any sound at all.

Comment: That's why you don't use the buggy kernel daily.